# How to hide H.map.Layer in here map?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I have added layer in map as follows

```
clusterLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider); 
map.getLayers().add(clusterLayer);
```

Now I want to hide/show layer on click of button. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the Provider
for example :

```
clusteredDataProvider.addEventListener('tap', function(event) {

//your code

 console.log(event.target.getData())}
```

for complete documentation kindly refer the below link 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-datamodel.html#h-map-datamodel

Comment: I want to hide/show layer which was added on map when any user click on button